# Period of nonlinear spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A mass on a frictionless table is attached to the midpoint of an originally unstretched spring fixed at the ends. If the mass is displaced a distance $A$ parallel to the table surface but perpendicular to the spring, it exhibits oscillations. What is the relation between the period of the oscillations and the displacement $A$?

The official solution:

> For large values of $A$, the mass performs simple harmonic motion, so the period is constant. For small values of $A$, the potential is quartic, and increases more slowly than the corresponding quadratic, so the period is larger than the limiting value.

Could someone please clarify this solution or write a solution of their own? Thanks! :D

Comment: "For large values of A ... the period is constant." Wrong: the mass *approximately* performs SHM, and the period is *approximately* constant.

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.